# kops kubernetes cluster with multiple DNS

Tags: kubernetes, kops

There are two parts to this.

1. I am using kops v1.17.0 to standup kubernetes cluster on ec2 instances. I am followinf these docs for doing so. https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kops/

on of the points go as follows.

> kops has a strong opinion on the cluster name: it should be a valid
> DNS name.

this got me confused. Can my cluster serve requests to only one DNS and its subdomains?

2. I tried this on a domain **example.com** I created a hosted zone for it. created a cluster named  example.com.k8s.local.

I pointed this domain to my clusters load balancer. and I can access example.com. All good till now.

now, I want one of the services in my cluster to be served on **abc.com**. I created another hosted zone, and a new record set within it which points to this load balancer.  I am expecting to visit abc.com and see this service but all I see is **nginx 404 not found**

Is this happening because of the first point I mentioned or totally separate issue?  If it is because of 1st point is there aa way around or one cluster is always tied to one domain in the kops world?

Comment: From what I see in documentation the answer here is the first point you mentioned, if you have domain example.com then instead of abc.com you should use, for example, dev.example.com as a [subdomain](https://kops.sigs.k8s.io/creating_subdomain/#create-subdomain), could you try it with your nginx and let me know if it works? About the follow up question, I don´t think there is a workaround for that, atleast I couldn´t find anything about that in documentation.

Comment: @jt97 contd. in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the first part is concerned, Yes I can serve multiple domains from same kubernetes cluster with this setup. upto certain version there was a hard requirement of matching domain name with cluster name, its not the case anymore.

Couple of things you need to consider. while issuing a certificate from ACM, make sure all your domains are listed

example

```
example.com
*example.com
bar.com
*.bar.com
```

make sure that all of the domains are validated and are not in pending or any other state.

I think reason for second issue was one of the domains in my certificate generated by ACM was invalid state and thus in pending state.

@jt97 ^^